# SQL Optimization for large tables and selecting based on key

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the response time on our server down to the 250ms range most queries take less than a millisecond this one takes a long time on it's own.. over 1500ms due to the large number of rows.  Here is the data structure, is there anything that can be done to reduce the time for this query, either but using a different query or setting my data up some way faster?

```
mysql> describe variant_bikes;

+------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| variant_id | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| bike_id    | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
+------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> describe cscart_product_option_variants;

+----------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| variant_id           | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+----------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe bikefilter_cache;
+---------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| bike_id | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| year    | smallint(6) unsigned  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| make    | varchar(20)           | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| line    | varchar(20)           | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| model   | varchar(90)           | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
+---------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> select count(*) from variant_bikes;

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  7577597 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1.85 sec)

mysql> select variant_id from variant_bikes where bike_id=112;
9366 rows in set (2.30 sec)
```

One thing I tried before and I think was much slower at least with the size it was then, was to have variant_bikes be a table with variant_id as is but the bike_ids field was varchar and/or text and you searched over a comma separated list.

The other thing I think of is maybe arranging all the tables into a different more efficient data structure.

Comment: How about `EXPLAIN`ing these queries?

Comment: Erm... I may be wrong, but it looks to me there's only one index - `(variant_id, bike_id)` - in `variant_bikes`; both fields are not foreign keys. Is that true? )

Comment: I can if it's still useful raina.  The primary key pair index, as a unit isn't a foreign key.  But the each part is.  if that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For best performance of that query, add an index `ON variant_bikes (bike_id, variant_id)`.

That will be a "covering" index for the query, and MySQL will be able to satisfy the query "using index" blocks only, without having to reference (lookup) any data blocks from the table.

**Q:** Why do we need this index when there is already an index on `(variant_id, bike_id)` ?

**A:** It has to do with the order of the columns in the index. The predicate (WHERE clause) in your query is on the `bike_id` column. For MySQL to use an index, that column needs to appear as the leading column in the index.

**Q:** What if I have an index on just the `(bike_id)` column.

**A:** MySQL is very likely to use that index. The query also needs to return the values from the `variant_id` column... for optimum performance, we want to satisfy the query from the index blocks only. Depending on the version of MySQL and the storage engine, MySQL may be able to return `variant_id` from an index on just `(bike_id)`, because the values of the primary key columns is the "pointer" back to the data blocks.

You can try adding that index, and then running an `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`, what you want to see as the last column (Extra) is "Using index", which indicates the query was satisfied from the index without need to reference an blocks from the table.

```
... key             Extra        
--- -------------   -------------
    bike_id_index   Using index
```

Comment: create index bike_id_index on variant_bikes (bike_id, variant_id);  It's less than a millisecond now thank you.  My question then is why did i have do add this index if the primary key already is an index.  Is it the order?  is on variant_bikes (variant_id, bike_id) a different index?  What if i only do it on variant_bikes (bike_id)?

Answer (score 0):

Your `variant_bikes` primary key is a composite key `(variant_id, bike_id)` and you're searching on the second half of that composite key. So you don't get to use the index.

Add an index on `bike_id` and all should be well.